# Copying a date column with three different colours from one workbook to another workbook in excel

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I am trying to transfer the entries in a Date column from one workbook to another using Vlookup. I could just transfer the data in the cell not the colour coding. Is it possible to transfer the colour code of each cell together with the data?

I have three different colours RED, GREEN and YELLOW which Corresponds to Incomplete, Complete and In process respectively. After tranferring the cell colour coding, I should be able to change it manually if process is completed.

Comment: This could be done in VBA. You will need to get the colour code of the RED, Green and yellow. Easiest way would be the RGB values. Then loop through the column check if the colour matches the RGB and if they do copy the value and colour to the other column.

Comment: Thanks Sam. i am beginner and I dont know how to do what you have said. I am looking for some sample code or file which would help me in figuring it out.

Comment: If you can get me the RGB value of the cells I can write some basic code which will show you what to do. TO get the RGB values go to the cell with the colour. Click on the error next to the fill, click more colours then Customer. It should then show the RGB values

Comment: And also what column you are using and what column it should go into

Answer (score 0):

Here is code which will if there is match in a column copy the colour over. Doesnt use a Vloopup as seemed a bit pointless if you already have the list you want to check against. If there is no match it will stay the default colour.

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim a As Range

For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns("C"))
    On Error GoTo NextOne
    Set a = Cells(WorksheetFunction.Match(Range("C" & i), Range("B1:B6"), 0), "B")
    Range("C" & i).Interior.Color = a.Interior.Color

NextOne:
    Resume nextOne2
nextOne2:
Next i
```

You will need to reference which workbook you want to use. You will need to look up how to reference workbooks. And change the columns where the data is.